# Converting Regular Backbone App to use Marionette.js

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am considering changing our current application to use Marionette.  The trouble is that there is currently a whole number of different views, models, and collections that have been made by other developers that use regular Backbone.

I figure I can't really convert the whole application in one go especially considering I didn't develop a whole bunch of it. I am considering just starting with the Application object and Router.

Is this going to be possible?  Can I start with that and convert the actual views later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently converted our backbone application to use marionette, and we started with creating a new marionette application and router, and then created a few regions and layouts which managed our older Backbone views.

We were then able to convert the old backbone views to Marionette's ItemViews and CompositeViews, and we found we were able to delete a lot of old code.

Any custom collections and models we kept untouched. You'll probably find you won't need to change them.

My advice is to have a good read through the [docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/tree/master/docs) and have a look through how other people have their application structured, and how their router works. There are a few [boilerplate examples](https://github.com/ptnplanet/Backbone.Marionette.Boilerplate/tree/master/public/app) and generators on github.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is yes, you can convert the app piece by piece over time.

And your strategy of starting with the Application and Router is good. I've done a few projects where I only used the Application, Router, and maybe the Module feature of Marionette, keeping the rest plain Backbone.

From the [Marionette Docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette):

> Like Backbone itself, you're not required to use all of Marionette
>   just because you want to use some of it. You can pick and choose which
>   features you want to use. This allows you to work with other Backbone
>   frameworks and plugins easily. It also means that you are not required
>   to engage in an all-or-nothing migration to begin using Marionette.

And even once you start converting the views, you can do it one view at a time, as needed.